# copying to removable storage with cecopy with ActiveSync

Tags: batch-file

I'm having an issue properly copying files to a mobile device here is the code:

```
cls
cecopy /is "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\App\*.reg" dev:"\My        Computer\Application\"
cecopy /is "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\App\*.key" dev:"\My Computer\Application\"
cecopy /is "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\App\radio.def" dev:"\My Computer\Application\"
cecopy /is "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\Plat\*.reg" dev:"\My Computer\Platform\"
cecopy /is "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\Plat\*.cpy" dev:"\My Computer\Platform\"
pause
```

Here is the error:

```
Connected.
Syncing from  <C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\Plat\*.cpy>  to  <dev:\My C
omputer\Platform">
 "patch111_1.cpy"               Copying (New) ...  0/1 k

Error copying: "C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\Plat\patch111_1.cpy" <to>
"\My Computer\Platform"\patch111_1.cpy"

Copy Failed
```

Is this happening because the destination is a removable storage therefore it doesn't have access or what?

EDIT: I tried just using the cecopy from the command line to see if it threw the same error and no. So this issue lies with doing from the command line by hand and doing it from a batch file?

here is the result from the command line:

```
C:\>cecopy /is "D:\Profiles\tbh643\Desktop\MKTools\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\Ap
p\abs_drivers.reg" dev:\Application
Connected.
Syncing from  <D:\Profiles\tbh643\Desktop\MKTools\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\App
\abs_drivers.reg>  to  <dev:\Application>
 "abs_drivers.reg"              Copying (Newer) ...  1/1 k  ok
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all quotes and only putting them around the whole string? `"cecopy /is C:\Flash 2\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\Depot Test\Plat\*.reg dev:\My Computer\Platform\"`

Comment: it won't recognize cecopy if i put the command in quotes

Comment: Why are there different paths in the command line example you give and the batch file?

Comment: @mbroshi woops forgot to state that both paths are correct I am actually supposed to have it run off of a network drive and have these files stored in multiple locations.